Icons not getting loaded in react-native project
I'm trying to create a new react-native app. This is my first project. I'm not able to see the icons in expo tab.
Project structure:



constants/icons.js

app/(tabs)/_layout.jsx
import { View, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Tabs, Redirect} from 'expo-router';
import { icons } from '../../constants';

const TabIcon = (icon, color, name, focused) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Image
                source={icon}
                resizeMode="contain"
                tintColor={color}
                className="w-6 h-6"
            />
            <Text className={`${focused ? 'font-psemibold' : 'font-pregular'} text-xs`}>

            </Text>
        </View>
    )
}

const TabsLayout = () => {
  return (
    <>
            <Tabs
                screenOptions={{
                    tabBarShowLabel: true
                }}
            >
                <Tabs.Screen
                    name="home"
                    
                    options={{
                        title: 'Home',
                        headerShown: false,
                        tabBarIcon: ({color, focused}) => (
                            <TabIcon 
                                icon={icons.home}
                            color={color}
                            name="Home"
                            focused={focused} />
                        )
                    }
                    }
                />
            </Tabs>
    </>
  )
}

export default TabsLayout

But I don't see home.png getting loaded in the emulator

Clearing the cache and doing build/pre-build in expo didn't help. I'm not sure how to proceed on this.
Please let me know if you have any further questions.
TIA

Try and use require instead of import in your constants.js:
const bookmark = require("../assets/icons/bookmark.png);
...

export {
  bookmark,
  ...
}

This has to do with how react-native handles static assets.

Still didn't work. Should I do anything to include assets to generate source/public assets? or do some build?

Once you add a new icon / any other asset to your app, you do have to rebuild it, if that was your question.
